Ошибка в коде, Python, aiogram, multiprocessing AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
Есть код
@router.message(F.video)
async def send_photo(message: Message, state: FSMContext, bot: Bot):
    data = await state.get_data()
    try:data['subscribe']
    except:
        await state.update_data(subscribe='0')
        data = await state.get_data()
        print(data)
    if data['subscribe'] == '1':
        global line
        line+=1
        await message.answer(f'Вы {line} в очереди')
        try:
            file_id = message.video.file_id
            file = await bot.get_file(file_id)
            await bot.download_file(file.file_path, f"video{message.chat.id}_{message.message_id}.mp4")
        except:
            await message.answer('Вес видео слишком большой, отправь другое!')
            pass

    original_video = mp.VideoFileClip(f"video{message.chat.id}_{message.message_id}.mp4")



    if await check(message, original_video):
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=save, args=(message, original_video))
        p1.run()



    else:
        await message.answer('Видео больше минуты, отправь другое!')
    line-=1
else:
    await message.reply('❌ Не вижу подписки, подпишись, чтобы продолжить\nt.me/formulafinansov', reply_markup=kb.subscribe)

ошибка
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 309, in _process_update
    response = await self.feed_update(bot, update, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 158, in feed_update
    response = await self.update.wrap_outer_middleware(
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\error.py", line 25, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\user_context.py", line 56, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\fsm\middleware.py", line 42, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 276, in _listen_update
    return await self.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 146, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 141, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 174, in _propagate_event
    response = await router.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 146, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 141, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 166, in _propagate_event
    response = await observer.trigger(event, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
  File "C:\Users\igrop\PycharmProjects\tg_bot_khdenis9\app\handlers.py", line 88, in send_photo
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(save, args=(message, original_video))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 82, in __init__
    assert group is None, 'group argument must be None for now'
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now

в чём может быть дело и как исправить?
функция save
def save(message, original_video: mp.VideoFileClip):
    need(message, original_video)
    message.answer_video_note(video_note=FSInputFile(f"video2_{message.chat.id}_{message.message_id}.mp4"))
    os.remove(f"video2_{message.chat.id}_{message.message_id}.mp4")

В need обработка видео

А почему в трейсе ошибки код программы другой, чем вы привели? В ошибке так: p1 = multiprocessing.Process(save, args=(message, original_video)), и первый аргумент без имени - это и есть причина проблемы, потому что этот аргумент - это group. А у вас в коде якобы так: p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=save, args=(message, original_video)) и это должно работать без ошибки.
